# Querying Github's GraphQL API for Pull Requests with a certain file extension

Tags: github, graphql

The problem I'm trying to solve is knowing the number of unique people who have submitted a PR in my GHE ORG that contains Terraform code.

I've found out how to list all PRs within my ORG in a certain timeframe, but when trying to tie it down to a particular file extension (.tf) it doesn't seem to work correctly.

````
  search(query: "org:MY-ORG is:pr created:>2023-05-01 extension:.tf", type: ISSUE, last: 100) {
    edges {
      node {
        ... on PullRequest {
          url
          title
          createdAt
          repository {
            id
          }
          author {
            login
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}```

This result provides one answer, however a search using the UI shows many more (that URL looks like this, if that helps: https://github.com/search?q=org%3AMY-ORG+tf&type=pullrequests&s=created&o=desc)

How can I pull all the PRs in this ORG from May 1st 2023 that have to do with Terraform?

Note: MY-ORG name was changed from my actual org name.

I have tried an org level search query using GHE's GraphQL API which returns only a single result, but I see many more results in this same ORG in GHE when searching "org:MY-ORG tf".

Just the first page of the UI shows 10 results, and I have confirmed they have the .tf extension/terraform code as part of the PR (I thought that was my problem, their last PR didn't include the .tf files even if they were in the repo, but that's not it.)
````